# Parsing results from html table

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

im trying to match some data from a html output but im not sure what i could do to perform it right. So, im using the following block of code to extract the content of access and groups information:

```
import requests
import lxml.etree as LE
import lxml.html as LH

url = "http://theurl"
r = requests.get(url,auth=('user', 'pass'))
html = r.text

root = LH.fromstring(html)
LE.strip_tags(root, 'b')
data_list = root.xpath("""//td[text()='grouplist']
                             /following-sibling::*""")[0]

accessList= data_list.xpath("""//td[text()='access']
                                 /following-sibling::*/text()""")

groups = data_list.xpath("""//td[text()='groups']
                                 /following-sibling::*/text()""")
```

if i print the accessList, i have the data that i want:

```
print accessList
['Administrators', 'group_a', 'group_b', 'group_c']
```

but when i print the groups, the returning result would be:

```
print groups:
['\n','\n','\n']
```

Having that information, what could be done in order to get:

```
print groups
['group_a', 'group_b', 'group_c']
```

Here, you can see the returning html result

```
<TABLE bgcolor="#dddddd" border="1" />
<TR>
   <TD valign="top"><B>grouplist</B></TD>
   <TD>
      <TABLE />
<TR>
   <TD>
      <TABLE bgcolor="#dddddd" border="1" />
<TR>
   <TD valign="top"><B>access</B></TD>
   <TD>Administrators</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
   <TD valign="top"><B>inUse</B></TD>
   <TD>true</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
   <TD valign="top"><B>groups</B></TD>
   <TD>
      <TABLE>
         <TR>
            <TD>group_a</TD>
         </TR>
         <TR>
            <TD>group_b</TD>
         </TR>
         <TR>
            <TD>group_c</TD>
         </TR>
      </TABLE>
   </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
   <TD valign="top"><B>deny</B></TD>
   <TD>
      <TABLE>
      </TABLE>
   </TD>
</TR>
```

EDIT : Html code can be tested here:  [html tester](http://www.draac.com/htmltester.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is 'LH'? What is 'LE'? Please provide working code snippets and not code fragments that don't make sense  without giving further details.

Comment: @CRUSADER , thanks for pointing that. le and lh is for lxml.etree and lxml.html. Now added on main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
groups = data_list.xpath("""//td[text()='groups']
                                 /following-sibling::td/table/tr/td/text()""")
```

or, a little less specifically,

```
groups = data_list.xpath("""//td[text()='groups']
                                 /following-sibling::*//td/text()""")
```

works. If that too specific for your purpose, you could instead define `groups` this way:

```
groups = data_list.xpath("""//td[text()='groups']
                                 /following-sibling::*""")[0]
```

and then use `text_content`:

```
groups = groups.text_content().split()
```

However, splitting the text content on whitespace may not work well if `group_a`, `group_b` and/or `group_c` were replaced with text that itself contains whitespace.

Comment: Thanks again unutbu. yes it is specific for that situation but i have many other html results that fits on that pattern matching.